# Java Generics with multiple declarations

Tags: java, generics

I'm implementing a class using Generics like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractTask<T,V>
{
  public void method1 (T param1, V param2) {}
}
```

Can the declaration `<T,K>` be variable? I'd like extend that class by this way:

```
public class TaskOne extends AbstractTask<Integer,String>
{
  public void method1 (Integer param1, String param2) {}
}

public class TaskTwo extends AbstractTask<Number,Object,Double>
{
  public void method1 (Number param1, Object param2, Double param3) {}
}
```

Is possible do this?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to compile it? I guess `TaskTwo` will not compile

Comment: It's not possible. It's VERY unclear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Thanks for all answers. I think that the best option is use meriton proposition: void method1(Object... args)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

You should change `V` from a plain `java.lang` type into a wrapper for the parameters.

```
public class TaskOne extends AbstractTask<Integer,StringWrapper>
{
  public void method1 (Integer param1, StringWrapper param2) {}
}

public class TaskTwo extends AbstractTask<Number,ObjectAndDoubleWrapper>
{
  public void method1 (Number param1, ObjectAndDoubleWrapper param3) {}
}

class ObjectAndDoubleWrapper {
    Object obj;
    Double doub;
}
```

etc.

Obviously, pick a more sensible name that reflects the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

No it is impossible, Java compiler enforces generics and you will get compilation error

Answer (score 0):

No, the number of type and method parameters must be the same for all instances of a generic class.

If we knew what you are trying to accomplish we might suggest alternatives. For instance, if this is about submitting tasks to a thread pool, you could do something like:

```
final int x = ...;
final String y = ...;
final Number n = ...;
new Runnable {
    @Override public void run() {
        // do something with x, y and n
    }
}
```

Or you could capture the parameters with an AOP proxy.

Or (if you don't need type safety), you could simply have

```
void method1(Object... args);
```

Or ...